# Sql Date query for birthday

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have table like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| name     | birthday   |
+----------+------------+
| jean     | 1988-08-09 |
| andrew   | 1990-09-20 |
| jennifer | 1980-09-05 |
| Harry    | 1985-10-25 |
| Chris    | 1987-09-22 |
+----------+------------+
```

I want to show result from birthday table where birthday just at September and date between 4 and 21 like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| name     | birthday   |
+----------+------------+
| andrew   | 1990-09-20 |
| jennifer | 1980-09-05 |
+----------+------------+
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,
       birthday 
FROM T
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 9
AND DAY(birthday) > 4
AND DAY(birthday) < 21;
```

Comment: can i add more condition to that like date between 4 and 21 so i can just get andrew and jennifer??

Comment: Absolutely. Add `AND DAY(birthday) >= 4 AND DAY(birthday) <= 21` to the end of that query. If you'll update your question to include that, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: done edit it.. :)
thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME,BIRTHDAY 
FROM YOURTABLE 
WHERE MONTH(BIRTHDAY)=9 AND DAY(BIRTHDAY) BETWEEN 4 AND 21
```